# Database does not supports streaming of resultSets on stored procedures

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-esb

I am getting "Database does not supports streaming of resultSets on stored procedures" when i try to call a stored procedure from Mule DB Connector which is returning a result set . However , Streaming of result set is possible for functions but i can not use functions as i have to insert to database tables , which is not allowed in SQL functions .
Any body have suggestions, Data returned is really large i need streaming .

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mule Community Edition it doesn't support streaming of stored procedures.
In this case you need to use jtds driver provided by third party vendor there will be syntax change in your connection URL format.
[Support Link](https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/Call-stored-procedure-on-Microsoft-SQL-Server-using-streaming-mode)

Thanks,
Vijay D.